# Key error while accesing a dataframe column in django

Tags: python, django, pandas, dataframe

[image: Screenshot of error]I am doing a Django project. I am converting my models into a dataframe for my convenience. I am stuck up in a step where I get a Keyerror of a column "Sales(L)".  If I run the same script in shell or spyder it is not throwing any error. Have a look at my script below.

```
smtv = MTD.pdobjects.all()
se = Salesexecutive.pdobjects.all()

smtv_df = smtv.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=True)
se_df = se.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=True)
se_df=se_df.rename(columns={'Customer_Account':'Customer_Code'})


smtv_df['Sales_Value']=smtv_df['Sales_Value'].astype(float)
smtv_df['Sales_Value']=(smtv_df['Sales_Value']/100000).apply(lambda x: round(x, 2))
smtv_df=smtv_df[(smtv_df['Invoice_Date']>=month_st) & (smtv_df['Invoice_Date']<=tdt)]
df = pandas.merge(smtv_df,se_df[['Customer_Code','Ecode','Sales_Executive']],on='Customer_Code', how='left')
df[['Ecode', 'Sales_Executive']] = df[['Ecode','Sales_Executive']].fillna('Unknown')

filt_df={}

filt_df['RGN']=request.POST.get('RGN', None)
filt_df['MKU']=request.POST.get('MKU', None)
filt_df['Vertical']=request.POST.get('Vertical', None)
filt_df['Channel']=request.POST.get('Channel', None)

fikt={k: v for k, v in filt_df.items() if v!=''}

for k,v in fikt.items():
    df=df[df[k]==v]



df1=pandas.pivot_table(df,index='MKU',values=['Sales_Value'],aggfunc='sum').replace(numpy.nan,0)
df1=df1.rename(columns={'Sales_Value':'Sales(L)'})
df1['Sale Target(L)']=df1['Sales(L)']*1.25
```

Please suggest some ideas to fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: please show us more of the error trace. on which line is the error thrown?

Comment: @dirkgroten. Please see the screenshot above. I get the error in the last line of the above script.

Comment: then something is probably wrong with the `rename()` you're doing. Set a breakpoint to check `df1` before the line that throws the error. I think you might need to do `df1.rename(index=str, columns={...})`.

Comment: No. The error still exists. Even if I keep the column name as it is in the dataframe without renaming i.e("Sales_Value), the same keyerror is thrown in the name of "Sales_Value".

Comment: You need to use a debugger to inspect `df` and `df1` at each step. That will show you where the column disappears.

Comment: The code runs correctly in spyder without any keyerror. But when I run it in django, the web page is showing the error.

Comment: It can’t be the exact same code since you’re manipulating `df` based on `request.POST` values. As I said, you need to use a debugger. No way we can help find the issue.

Comment: This can’t be right: `df = df[df[k]==v]`, can it?